# How can I setup my mac (OS X Yosemite) as an internet gateway

Tags: network, osx-server, server.app, firewall

It should be possible, but I searched for a day and cannot get a decent HowTo. There seemed to be a Gateway Setup Assistant, but the Wikipedia link only goes to the server app now. Maybe it is easier than I think, but I cannot get it to work.

The setup should be:

**Router** <-- *USB ethernet* --> **MAC_GW** <-- *ethernet* --> **switch** <-> internal network

The MAC_GW is a Mac Mini (OS X Yosemite) with an USB ethernet adapter. Internet access is possible from the Mac Mini over this adapter. WiFi is disabled for now.

I installed the server.app and got the DHCP service running, so machines in the internal network get IP addresses assigned. Unfortunately, the server app doesn't show any settings for gateway, NAT, bridging, firewall. The help function is just as helpful as the Apple features website. :(

Now for the question:
What do I have to configure, so machines from the internal network get internet access?

Additionally: How can I setup a firewall to control outside access?

**UPDATE:**
as @Froggard hinted, Internet Sharing worked in giving access to the internal network. However, I have no control over the DHCP addresses given by the server, firewall, user access, etc. The server.app DHCP is turned off now, because it cannot be assigned to the internal network adapter.

Maybe someone can still give details on how to enable firewall or control the components involved?

Comment: Have you tried Internet Sharing? I believe that'll do at least part of this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OS X Yosemite doesn’t have support for natd binary or ipfw anymore. Instead pfctl is used.

I assume the following IP-adresses/netmasks:

```
Router: 192.168.0.1/24
Mac mini gateway: en0: 192.168.0.2/24 gateway 192.168.0.1 en1: 192.168.1.2/24
Internal network: 192.168.1.0/24
```

1. First you have to enable forwarding on your Mac computer with following commands:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
   ```
2. In order to do NAT you have to create a pfctl rule. Create a file called "nat-rules" with the following content:

   ```
   nat on en0 from en1 to any -> (en0)
   ```
3. Save the file and now start pfctl using the rule from the file we have created earlier:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -d #disables pfctl
   sudo pfctl -F all #flushes all pfctl rules
   sudo pfctl -f /Path/to/file/nat-rules -e #starts pfctl and loads the rules from the nat-rules file
   ```
4. Now configure a static route on your router:

   192.168.1.0/24 (the internal network) -> 192.168.0.2 (Mac mini IP-address of the external interface connected to the router)
5. Enable the DHCP-service on your Mac mini gateway:

   - Name: choose a name
   - Network Interface: en1
   - Starting IP address: 192.168.1.10
   - Ending IP address: 192.168.1.100
   - Subnet Netmask: 255.255.255.0
   - Router: 192.168.1.2
   - DNS: some DNS-server (e.g. 8.8.8.8)
6. Now use pfctl to add rules or get a pfctl-GUI like [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/) or [Murus](http://www.murusfirewall.com/) to configure your firewall. Both apps should also allow you to enable NAT (step 2/3)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried **System Preferences** > **Sharing** and enabling **Internet Sharing** (select the USB connection to the router as the Internet interface you're sharing)?

Comment: That's the most simple answer and worked for me flawlessly.

Comment: But how to config IP addresses on Mac (the Mac used as router) and other computers?

Answer (score 2):

As an expansion of [samh's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219186/265111), and to answer the question in the [comment from Frozen Flame](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192089/how-can-i-setup-my-mac-os-x-yosemite-as-an-internet-gateway#comment420800_219186), here is how you can use Internet Sharing, and also control which IP address range is used:

### Change default DHCP IP Range for macOS Internet Sharing

macOS Defaults to using 192.168.0.xxx as the DHCP range when you use the Internet Sharing feature to share (for example) an ethernet connection over WiFi.

This can be problematic if you are trying to log in to another network over VPN that uses the same IP Address range, or you have some other conflict.

To change the range that macOS uses, first turn off internet sharing, and quit System Preferences, then enter the following commands into the terminal:

(you can replace the first two IP Ranges as needed)

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberStart 192.168.22.1
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberEnd 192.168.22.254
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkMask 255.255.255.0
```

Then re-open System Preferences and re-enable Internet Sharing, and you should be good to go.

To read out the current config use the following command:

```
sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat
```

And that's pretty much it!

I originally found the commands for setting the NAT ranges here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090510120814850