# What is the modern way to do port-forwarding on El Capitan? (forward port 80 to 8080)

Tags: macos, firewall, network

The old utility [`ipfw`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipfirewall) was discouraged in recent versions of Mac OS X and is now gone from El Capitan.

What is the modern way to do port forwarding in El Capitan?

I simply want port 80 to forward to port 8080.

Answer (score 94):

To forward all port 80 traffic to port 8080, you can enter the following from the Terminal command line.

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

Taken from https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: and from the mentioned article, to remove it, `sudo pfctl -F all -f /etc/pf.conf`, and to display your current port forwarding rules, `sudo pfctl -s nat`

Comment: keep in mind that this solution doesn't add rules but replaces any other rule loaded before, including the `pf.conf` file

Comment: Caution, this answer breaks access directly to port 8080 in weird ways. This answer is better: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332603

Answer (score 37):

The modern way to forward ports in El Capitan is using `pf`. In the example below all port 80 requests are forwarded to port 8080 on the same host. Please adjust the redirections to your needs.

1. Create an anchor file *org.user.forwarding* in /private/etc/pf.anchors

   ```
   sudo touch /private/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding
   ```

   with the following content and a trailing empty line

   ```
   rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
   rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
   rdr pass on en1 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
   ```

   or

   ```
   rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
   ```
2. Modify the file /private/etc/pf.conf but keep a trailing empty line

   original file:

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   ```

   to

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "org.user.forwarding"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   load anchor "org.user.forwarding" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding"
   ```
3. Parse and test your anchor file to make sure there are no errors:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding
   ```
4. Now modify /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist from

   ```
   <array>
       <string>pfctl</string>
       <string>-f</string>
       <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
   </array>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <array>
       <string>pfctl</string>
       <string>-e</string>
       <string>-f</string>
       <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
   </array>
   ```

   You have to disable System Integrity Protection to accomplish this. After editing the file reenable SIP. After rebooting your Mac pf will be enabled (that's the -e option).

   In **macOS 10.15 Catalina** (and its read-only system volume) you have to edit the launch daemon in Recovery Mode. SIP is disabled by default in Recovery Mode - so no need to execute *csrutil*:

   ```
   /Volumes/Name_of_boot_volume/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/Name_of_boot_volume/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
   ```

   with the default boot volume name *Macintosh HD* this is:

   ```
   /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
   ```

   Alternatively you may create your own launch daemon similar to the answer here: [Using Server 5.0.15 to share internet WITHOUT internet sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229266/93229).

After a system update or upgrade some of the original files above may have been replaced and you have to reapply all changes.

If you want to forward across different interfaces you have to enable this in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
```

Comment: Why isn't there a simple command to do this anymore? It's too complicated now.

Comment: @klanomath -- this works and i can forward port x to port y on 127.0.0.1 etc, but i am unable to forward ports to my windows vm running on paralles desktop, Any idea ? here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695684/osx-elcapitan-portforwarding-to-parallels-vm-using-pfctl

Comment: Does not seem to work when forwarding port to a VM which is running on parallels desktop

Comment: @sudhir You did not successfully link to your new Question. By default a Parallels VM is not visible to the network, as a security precaution. You can change a setting in the VM’s configuration to make the VM visible. And remember, `ping` is your friend in diagnosing network problems.

Comment: @suhir's question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262708/os-x-el-capitan-port-forwarding-to-parallels-vm-using-pfctl

Comment: @klanomath What is the "one command" we should "see below"? I do not follow.

Comment: @BasilBourque When I wrote the comment, [Sal Ferrarello's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248064/93229) had less up-votes than mine ;-). It doesn't survive a restart though and you have to enter it again after a reboot...

Comment: @klanomath Thanks. FYI, you can link to another Answer using the URL found in the "share" link on that Answer. Ex: See [the Answer by Sal Ferrarello](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248064/17907)

Comment: @BasilBourque I was in a hurry probably and just wrote a quick and dirty comment (without a proper link)...

Comment: I'm running Puma-dev which runs its HTTPS on `9283`. I added in `org.user.forwarding` : `rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9283` and the relative anchors in pf.conf, restarted them with the commands `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` . But when I try to access the website via `mywebsite.dev` I get no server response. But if I explicitly write the port, it works. What perchance might I be missing here?

Comment: I am on High Sierra and am getting a syntax error when I test (step #3) - I copy/pasted the above into /private/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding - any suggestions as to what to look for?

Comment: @allicarn Did you add an empty new line (1x enter key) at the end of both files?

Comment: That was it!  Sorry, I missed it in your instructions. Thanks!

Comment: The method of editing `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` doesn't work in Catalina due to the [read-only file system](https://superuser.com/questions/1495124/read-only-file-system-when-i-try-to-touch-in-mac-os-catalina) (even with SIP disabled)

Comment: @JamesCushing In Catalina you can edit it booted to Recovery Mode! Added a description in my answer...

Answer (score 9):

To extend solution from @sal-ferrarello answer, I created two super-basic Shell Scripts to **enable** or **disable** redirecting **without compromising already existing entries** in `pf`.

**I. First find what entries do you already have with:**

`sudo pfctl -s nat`

My output was like:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

What interests us is actual entries so ommit first two info lines.

**II. Create `enable.sh` script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "
nat-anchor \"com.apple/*\" all
rdr-anchor \"com.apple/*\" all
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
sudo pfctl -s nat
```

First two lines after `echo` are the entries that were already there. Third line is with new redirect – in this case 80 to 8080. At the end we call `sudo pfctl -s nat` to see if changes were applied.

**III. Create `disable.sh` script:**

Similar to `enable.sh` we create script, but without 80->8080 redirect, but with previous already existing entries:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "
nat-anchor \"com.apple/*\" all
rdr-anchor \"com.apple/*\" all
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
sudo pfctl -s nat
```

Answer (score 2):

I've developed an App for port forwarding on macOS. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/hronro/iPortForwarder

It allows you to easily forward a single port or a range of ports without modifying the system firewall.

[image: scrrenshot]