# OS X El Capitan port forwarding to Parallels VM using pfctl

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, firewall

I have Parallels Desktop 11, which does not have support port forwarding to VMs (just the Pro version supports it). So I am trying to use pfctl to forward ports to my Parallels VM.

I have followed this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331) to setup the port forwarding.
Forwarding is enabled with `sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`

I have specified this rule.

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 51414 -> 10.211.55.9 port 51414
```

10.211.55.9 is the static IP of the Parallels VM.

However the port forwarding does not work for VM. It can successfully forward port x to port y on 127.0.0.1 but can not forward port x from Mac to port x on Parallels VM.

What could be going wrong? Is it Parallels which is dropping packets etc?

Comment: Looked at this gist https://gist.github.com/kujohn/7209628 looks like lots of other ppl has problem forwarding ports to different ip

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions for your problem with Parallels Desktop 11 (this doesn't apply to Parallels Desktop Pro/Enterprise 11, which both provide a convenient interface to configure port forwarding - nonetheless the solutions should work also in those enhanced versions):

Instead of attaching the VM's network interface to the "Shared Network" use a bridged interface (e.g. en0 or en1) and configure it with a IP/netmask in the respective network. Then you don't need NAT/port forwarding.

---

If you insist on a NAT'ed network do the following:

In the example below I use `nc` as server. To run a server enter `nc -l -4 port` and to connect to this server use `nc server-IP port`. You may also specify a source port: `nc -p source-port server-IP port`.

Here I use `nc -l -4 11111` on the VM. To connect to this server I would run `nc server-IP 11111` from a host in the same network. After starting the server and connecting the client you can simply enter some text, which is sent to the other console. To connect from a third host in a different network to the VM nc-server I want to use `nc NAT-host-IP 22222`. So I have to forward NAT-host-IP:22222 to VM-IP:11111. NAT-host in this case is the Mac hosting the Parallels VM.

1. attach the VM guest's network interface to the "Host-only Network". Usually Parallels' host-only network has the following host configuration (check this by entering `ifconfig` on the host machine):

   ```
   vnic1: ...
   ...
   inet 10.37.129.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.37.129.255
   ```

   So configure the VM guest as following:

   - IP: 10.37.129.x (with x ≠ 0,1,2,255) - below I assume it's 10.37.129.10
   - Netmask: 255.255.255.0
   - Gateway: 10.37.129.2
   - DNS: a real DNS server like 8.8.8.8
2. On the NAT-host machine enable forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf:

   ```
   net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
   net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
   ```

   and reboot the host.
3. On the NAT-host machine (with an example IP of en0: 192.168.0.2) create an anchor file org.user.forwarding in /private/etc/pf.anchors

   ```
   sudo touch /private/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding
   ```

   with the following content and a trailing empty line:

   ```
   rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 22222 -> 10.37.129.10 port 11111
   ```
4. On the NAT-host machine modify the file /private/etc/pf.conf but keep a trailing empty line

   original file:

   ```
   ...
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   ```

   to

   ```
   ...
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "org.user.forwarding"
   nat on en0 proto {tcp, udp, icmp} from 10.37.129.0/24 to any -> en0
   pass from {lo0, 10.37.129.0/24} to any keep state
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   load anchor "org.user.forwarding" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding"
   ```
5. Parse and test your anchor and your pf.conf file to make sure that there are no errors:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
   ```
6. Enable pf with:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```
7. To test this start the nc server on the VM with  `nc -l -4 11111`. Now on a third host in your physical network enter `nc 192.168.0.2 22222`.

---

After a reboot you have to start pf again. If you want to enable pf permanently check my other [pf related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A93229+pf) answers.

After a system update or upgrade some of the original files above may have been replaced and you have to reapply all changes.

Comment: Will try it out..