# Corresponding ipfw rules in MacOS for this Iptables rules

Tags: macos, network, vmware, ipfw

I need to give Internet access to a VM under Vmware fusion 7 in Host-Only mode. I know how to do it in Linux, with the following IPtables rules:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Can this be done in MacOS Sierra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable NAT for a host-only network in VMware Fusion do the following:

1. Enable forwarding by adding a file /etc/sysctl.conf with the content:

   ```
   net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
   ```

   and reboot
2. Connect the Mac to the host-only network and make a note of the network/netmask of the host.only network:

   [image]
3. Enter `ifconfig` to get the vmnet IP of the Mac

   ```
   ...
   vmnet3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
           ether 00:50:56:c0:00:03 
           inet 192.168.9.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.9.255
   ```
4. In the IP setting of the guest VM enter an IP/netmask according to the host-only network settings (with the example above that's in the range 192.168.9.2-254/255.255.255.0), a gateway (the vmnet3 IP of the hosting Mac from step 3 - here: 192.168.9.1) and a DNS server.
5. Open the pf.conf file with:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/pf.conf
   ```

   and add the lines:

   ```
   nat on {en0, en1} proto {tcp, udp, icmp} from 192.168.9.0/24 to any -> {en0, en1}
   pass from {lo0, 192.168.9.0/24} to any keep state
   ```

   after the line `rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"`.

   Depending on your Mac and your network configuration only one interface is sufficient (either en0 or en1). Also use the proper network/netmask (your vmnet config instead of 192.168.9.0/24)!.

   Save the file and exit nano.
6. Check your pf.conf with:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
   ```
7. If no error occurs enable pf with:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf
   ```

---

After a reboot you have to relaunch pf because it's not started automatically while booting. To launch pf while booting check step 4 in this answer: [What is the modern way to do port-forwarding on El Capitan? (forward port 80 to 8080)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to/230331#230331)

Comment: Works well with Virtualbox and ''Host-only Adapter" mode

Comment: @klanomath, thanks for an excellent answer. Why do you NAT on `{en0,en1}`, when `ifconfig` reports the interface as `vmnet3`? Furthermore, please correct "the IP of the Mac from step 2" to "the IP of the Mac from step 3".

Comment: @Shuzheng You have to enable NAT on a "public" interface (which usually is either en0 or en1) of a NAT gateway. Vmnet3 is a "private" interface by definition and has no connection to the world.

Comment: @klanomath, indeed, but doesn't the packages pass the vmnet3 interface (and not en0), when going from the host-only network to the Internet? The guest VM sends it's packets to the vmnet3 interface of the host.