# Execute alias with sudo at session startup

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, alias

I created the following alias and put it into my `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias kiosk-proxy="echo \"rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080\" | sudo pfctl -ef -"
```

It's basically a pf rule which redirects all incoming traffic with the destination port 80 to 127.0.0.1:8080 (but what it does is not important, it's just to give you some context)

Currently, I have to manually run this at every session startup, I'd like to automate it.

It would be rather simple if it didn't need `sudo` rights, I'd just put `kiosk-proxy` in my ~/.bash_profile, I guess.

But since it needs sudo, it's gonna ask for the password and I doubt it's gonna prompt it. So... How can I execute this alias with sudo rights without asking for the password? Also, it needs to know there is such alias existing in `~/.zshrc`, which may not have been loaded yet. Worse case, I can move the alias to another file.

Comment: A few things....Do you want this only for a shell environment for a particular user or do you want this for the whole computer?  Are you using zsh or bash?  You mention both.  Why wouldn't you want to execute that command as a *script*?

Comment: I'm mostly relying on Zsh, but thought I'd have to use bash_profile since it's the default profile file. I don't really care if it's for a single user or all of them, I only have one user on this computer. I could execute it as a script as well, it's just that, currently, it's an alias. So I used it as example.

Comment: Do you want this to run only when you're logged in, or when the computer starts up? I have the root user enabled on my box, so I have no idea what a Mac looks like without that... but the root user has it's own startupitems and doesn't need permissions to run stuff so, in theory, that should work for you? G>

Comment: bash_profile is not read by zsh - so stick to one or the other

Comment: Good to know, I though bash was always executed, having zsh as default terminal I figured I could have aliases in either .bashrc or .zshrc and it would work the same. Thought it was identical for the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling pf (with the rdr rule) with a command/alias or a shell script/function in your bash/zsh profile like in your question is neither common nor good practice. It is possible though:

To disable a password prompt modify the sudoers file:

Open Terminal and enter `sudo visudo` to modify the file */etc/sudoers*.

Change the part:

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/pfctl
```

and save the file.

If you don't know *vi*: after entering `sudo visudo` you have to change to *insert mode* by hitting <kbd>i</kbd>. Enter the additional line as indicated above. To leave *insert mode* hit <kbd>esc</kbd>. Then enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to write the modified file to disk and quit vi.

**bash:**

Entering `kiosk-proxy` shouldn't require a password anymore. You can then simply add `kiosk-proxy` as a separate line in your bash_profile (after the `alias kiosk-proxy ...`line)

After exiting the shell, pf won't be disabled and the passed rule is still redirecting! To disable pf and the rdr rule while exiting the (bash) shell, create a file with `touch ~/.bash_logout` and the content `sudo pfctl -d`.

**zsh:**

The same works with ~/.zprofile containing:

```
alias kiosk-proxy="echo \"rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080\" | sudo pfctl -ef -"

kiosk-proxy
```

and ~/.zlogout containing

```
sudo pfctl -d
```

---

A more [recommended way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331/93229) is to simply add the rdr rule in pf.conf and enable pf while booting.