# Mapping port 80 to 8080 but maintain explicit 8080 access

Tags: network, pfctl

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331/212942) to map port 8080 to 80 on my mac. This works a treat, except for the fact that I can no-longer access `http://localhost:8080` explicitly through Chrome (it never responds).

Put differently, I can start an http server on my machine listening on port 8080, which, having remapped my ports will work when I navigate to `localhost` in my browser, but *doesn't* work if I navigate to `localhost:8080`.

This causes issues with certain library code that explicitly includes the server port in its http requests.

How do I configure port forwarding in such a way that *both* `localhost:8080` and `localhost` will send requests to my local server?

Comment: If you disable the port forwarding does connecting to `localhost:8080` work again?

Comment: @nohillside is there a command to disable port forwarding quickly without turning off SIP etc.?

Comment: `/private/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.forwarding` can be edited with SIP enabled

Comment: @nohillside - thanks - I disabled the rules and `localhost:8080` works again (obviously `localhost` doesn't).

Comment: Hmm, ok, interesting :-) I didn't expect `pf` to behave like that, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Before answering your question, let me provide some background information for those unfamiliar with port forwarding on macOS**: port forwarding involves replacing destination addresses and ports of incoming packets to redirect connections to different hosts and/or ports. macOS achieves port forwarding by applying `rdr` (redirection) rules to the packet filter device `/dev/pf`. For example, this rule:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to 213.32.64.5 port 80 -> 10.4.1.2 port 8080
```

forwards incoming IPv4 packets sent to `213.32.64.5:80` to `10.4.1.2:8080` (the `pass` keyword prevents redirected packets from being blocked by filter rules, see [here](http://artemisa.unicauca.edu.co/~mtrujillo/OpenBSD/pf/rdr.html#filter) for more information). To apply the rule, you can either use `pfctl` or modify `/etc/pf.conf`, as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to). For more information on `rdr` rules, see `man pf.conf`.

**Now to your question:**

> How do I configure port forwarding in such a way that both
>   localhost:8080 and localhost will send requests to my local server?

**To be able to access both the original and the redirected port reliably**, you must exclude the destination address and port (127.0.0.1:8080) from being redirected:

```
echo 'no rdr inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
' | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

(Tested on a clean install of macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.)

The command above will overwrite all existing rules, so I'd recommend it only for testing. You can then reload your Mac's default packet filter rules with `sudo pfctl -F all -ef /etc/pf.conf` and add the rules:

```
no rdr inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

to `pf.conf` as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to).

> I followed the instructions [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331/212942) to map port 8080 to 80 on
>   my mac. This works a treat, except for the fact that I can no longer
>   access http://localhost:8080 explicitly through Chrome (it never
>   responds).

[This comment](https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/#comment-14130) on Sal Ferrarello's blog describes a similar behavior. I was able to reproduce it, but in my tests the connection to port 8080 worked intermittently, or more precisely: I could load  http://127.0.0.1:8080, but after that first connection, clicking any link on the website timed out. Some time later, though, I was able to connect once again, just to experience in any subsequent connections the same time-outs as before.

I had to do quite a bit of packet sniffing, I'd like to share the commands I used to log packets that match the `rdr` rule (that's what the [`log` parameter](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/logging.html) below is for) using the "pflog0" pseudo-device (see `man pflog` and `man pf.conf` for details):

```
echo 'no rdr log inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr inet log proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
' | sudo pfctl -ef -
sudo ifconfig pflog0 create
sudo tcpdump -X -n -e -i pflog0
```

Comment: Great answer and a working solution! Thanks for the additional detail - really useful.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe I'm glad you found my answer useful!