# How to do port forwarding on macOS Catalina? Example: Forward web requests on port 80 to port 8080

Tags: macos, network, catalina

What is the modern way to do port-forwarding on macOS Catalina 10.15.7?

What tools & commands does one use to effect simple port-forwarding?

For example, I have a web server listing on port 8080. I want incoming requests on port 80 to be sent to port 8080 for that web server to receive.

I know the tooling and approaches for port-forwarding have been changing over the years. I don't know the most modern way appropriate to Catalina.

Comment: Somewhat odd to see the words "modern" and "Catalina" appear in the same sentence in March 2023. Catalina was superseded in 2020 by Big Sur, and there have been 3 major releases since then.

Comment: I think you'll find this has already been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to)

Comment: @luckman212 Catalina has received security updates, at least [of 2021](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212326).