# How to use mac as a full router with DHCP, DNS, Port Fowarding etc.?

Tags: macos, network, dns, internet-sharing, router

I know I can use internet sharing in macOS to share the internet connection provided to one network interface over one or more other network interfaces on my Mac.  However, the feature set is VERY limited.  No choice of DHCP range.  No DHCP reservations.  No port forwarding.  etc.

MacOS Server has a DHCP server and other services, but none of them actually share the mac's internet connection in any way, nor can they be used to control or add those features to the native macOS's internet sharing feature mentioned above.

Are there any software tools, Apple or third party, that can do what internet sharing does (share my mac's internet connection out over one or more other network interfaces), but with the kind of additional features listed above?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**  Thanks to the two answers so far that have pointed me to the two pf based solutions.  Admittedly, I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require a virtual machine, and a solution that doesn't require command line stuff but further research has pointed me to IceFloor and Murus and a couple of other GUIs for pfctl.  However, pfctl seems to be a firewall not a router, and what I want is routing.  Still, I'm limited in my understanding of all this and it's possible this is what I want still because...

With some more research and I find this:

https://developcents.com/2013/08/12/routers-switches-firewalls-differences/

Under the Firewalls section it says "Unlike routers and switches, firewalls are network security appliances"  and "... most perimeter firewalls also have routing capabilities (although that is not a requirement)."

So... I'm guessing you guys are pointing me to the pfctl firewall utility because it's one of those firewalls that has routing capabilities, meaning if I want to use it purely as a router and not use any of the firewall functionality, I will be able to do that.  Is that correct?  And does it have included in its routing capabilities the functionality I'm looking for as described in the original question above (specifically, choice of DHCP range, DHCP reservations, and port forwarding)?

I realize it's possible I could answer this myself with enough study of the documentation and of networking in general, but the original reason for the question is because I'm used to setting up Apple Airport base station with the Airport utility and the original question is seeking something with that kind of clarity but for setting up a Mac instead of an Airport base station to do it.

Any of that make sense and can anyone help me, given all that extra info?

Comment: macOS Server DHCP Service and DNS Service may assist with that.

Comment: @Josh Please expand on how DHCP and DNS handles firewall, NAT, port forwarding, etc?

Comment: @Josh.  Unfortunately that's not the case.  I haven't quite figured out how to make those do anything useful, but from the documentation I understand them to be services available for handling network traffic etc. with something else being the router.  They don't offer any routing services themselves.  Even less useful, they don't work in conjunction with the built in routing service (macOS's internet sharing) in macOS.  Seems pretty stupid to me, but that seems to be the way of it.  This is a large part of why I'm asking my question in the first place.

Comment: DHCP Service allows you to edit lease settings, IP range, subnet mask, DNS (alter more settings in DNS service), etc.

Comment: @Josh. Hi, yes I understand that.  Thanks.  But how does that help make the Mac a router?

Comment: I added it as a comment because it does not completely make it a router but it helps with your question. You said "choice of DHCP range...DHCP reservations" I have answered how to control those two parts.  Additionally a router deals with DNS, I have provided a solution to that too. My solution doesn't make your Mac a router but it helps do the things you want similarly to what a router does hence why it was added as a comment.

Comment: If you need help setting it up I may be able to help in a separate chat.

Comment: @Josh, Ok thanks.  I'm not sure how to do a separate chat so could I invite you to start one with me?  Primarily the question then is: Internet sharing makes the Mac a router, but not one that those services can interact with, so is there any way to make the Mac a router that those services can interact with?  Perhaps the pfctl suggestions from the other two answers so far might answer/resolve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76726/discussion-between-josh-and-davidt).

Comment: Check my answers (search string: `user:93229 Internet Sharing`) - especially https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248904/93229 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228936/using-server-5-0-15-to-share-internet-without-internet-sharing)! Apple's Internet Sharing is based on pf. By installing some additional tools with brew **and** Murus as GUI you get all you need (e.g DHCP range/reservation).

Comment: I tend to vote to close this question because it's too broad. Basically the answer is: yes, it can be done (but the learning curve is steep).

Comment: @Allan Check my answer please.

Answer (score 6):

Simple...*yeah right*....

**Note:** Someone please edit this to include only `default` commands

### Covered in this answer

- DHCP (Range, reservations, mask, router, lease time)
- DNS
- Port Forwarding
- Setup
- Text Book

---

### DHCP

### **Range**

**Option 1:** `com.apple.nat.plist`[[1]](https://www.amsys.co.uk/change-internet-sharing-subnet-on-mac-os-x/)

1. `sudo cp /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist.orig` // Backup just incase
2. `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberStart [START IP ADDRESS]`
3. `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberStart [END IP ADDRESS]`

**Option 2:**  `/etc/bootpd.plist`

1. Turn on Internet Sharing
2. `sudo nano /private/etc/bootpd.plist`

3.

```
<key>net_range</key>
        <array>
             <string>[START IP ADDRESS]</string>
             <string>[END IP ADDRESS]</string>
        </array>
```

### **Lease Time**

1. Turn on Internet Sharing
2. `sudo nano /private/etc/bootpd.plist`// No need for backup it will recreate incase any issues

3.

```
 <key>lease_max</key>
      <integer>[MAX TIME]</integer>
 <key>lease_min</key>
      <integer>[MIN TIME]</integer>
```

### **Subnet Mask**

**Option 1:** `com.apple.nat.plist`

1. `sudo cp /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist.orig` // Backup just incase
2. `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkMask [SUBNET MASK]`

**Option 2:**  `/etc/bootpd.plist`

1. Turn on Internet Sharing
2. `sudo nano /private/etc/bootpd.plist`

3.

```
<key>net_mask</key>
     <string>[SUBNET MASK]</string>
```

**Router IP**
1. Turn on Internet Sharing

2. `sudo nano /private/etc/bootpd.plist`

3.

```
<key>dhcp_router</key>
                    <string>[ROUTER IP ADDRESS]</string>
```

---

### **DNS**

### **Change Server**

1. Turn on Internet Sharing
2. `sudo nano /private/etc/bootpd.plist`

3.

```
<key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
     <array>
         <string>[DNS SERVER IP]</string>
     </array>
```

**Alter Settings**

**Option 1:** macOS Server

- Use [macOS Server](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.6/#/apd1E0474ED-5AD9-4463-A37C-0307042475D7) | [DNS Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu2b5IKYhc0)
- Once you turn it on and alter all setting it will say "Set your network DNS settings to [DNS SERVER IP] to use this server"

  - Change the Server (how to is above) to this IP address

**Option 2:** `/etc/hosts` [4](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/07/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/)

1. `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`
2. IP [TAB] DOMAIN

---

### **Port Forwarding** [5](https://superuser.com/questions/473039/pfctl-port-forwarding-in-mac-osx)

---

### **Setup/*Turn on Internet Sharing*** [6](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/05/enable-internet-sharing-mac-os-x/)

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Sharing
3. Select the pull-down next to "Share your connection from:" and choose an interface
4. Check off the interfaces you would like to "Share your connection from"
5. Click WiFI Options and alter settings there
6. Once finished, Click "OK" then Check "Internet Sharing" on the left

---

### **TextBook/Glossary** (Not alphabetical)

[Router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing))

[DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol): Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol

[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System): Domain Name System

[Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking))

[Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)): [macOS Sierra: Firewall pane of Security & Privacy System Preferences](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25551?locale=en_US)

[IP Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

[Subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)

[DHCP Reservations](https://serverfault.com/questions/544619/static-ip-vs-dhcp-reservation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[IP Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding): [Check if Port is open](http://canyouseeme.org)

[Modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem): Modulator-demodulator (Who named this???)

**Feel Free to edit and add Text Book Terms**

Comment: In process of creating a GUI app for this...

Comment: There are some issues with this and it’s a bit inconsistent I will change soon.

Comment: As far as DHCP lease time: it's only present in /etc/bootpd.plist _after_ the interface I'm sharing to is connected, so is there a way to verify that changing it from 86400 actually gets picked up?

Comment: @alesplin iirc you need to lock the file sometimes to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, you can download [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) and install it in a virtual machine using your choice of VM host app, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a free example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Hoping to do this without a VM, and it should be possible, given what internet sharing can do.  And Allan's answer below suggests it's possible, even if I have to resort to command line.  I've added some more to the question above seeking further clarification regarding yours and Allan's answers.  If you're able to offer any more based on that, then thanks in advance! :)

Comment: PS.  I'd upvote you for this but don't have enough reputation for that yet, apparently. But please know I would if I could 

Comment: @DavidT pfSense was designed from the ground up as a router / firewall. It does make use pf, I'd almost consider it a GUI for pf with some extended capability. Is there a reason a VM wouldn't be an acceptable solution? pfSense will run with very minimal resources.

Answer (score 2):

PF firewall.  It's already included with macOS.  It's the same firewall that is at the core of pfSense's products.

[Full PF documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that.  Sounds promising.  And seems consistent with Scottmeup's answer above.  I've added some more to the question above seeking further clarification regarding yours and his answers.  If you're able to offer any more based on that, then thanks in advance! :)

Comment: PS.  I'd upvote you for this but don't have enough reputation for that yet, apparently. But please know I would if I could 