# Can I use a USB Wi-Fi adapter to extend a Wi-Fi connection on my MacBook

Tags: wifi, high-sierra

I want to share an internet connection (Wi-Fi) through my laptop. I understand that you can't receive internet data and create a network simultaneously using the same internal adapter, but what if I bought a Wi-Fi adapter, like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B075G35YFV/ref=as_at?slotNum=7&SubscriptionId=AKIAINYWQL7SPW7D7JCA&linkCode=g14&imprToken=5rijxEEmC.00yXc888gfIQ&creativeASIN=B075G35YFV&tag=dotdash21-21&creative=165953&camp=2025), so one can receive data and the other transmit it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You are asking two distinct, though related, questions; please limit it to one specific question.  However, in an attempt to get you going re:  creating the network... the first is an [ad-hoc network](https://bit.ly/2rWm97l), the second [turns your MacBook into a router](https://apple.co/2Li91kH) and is more applicable to the overall question.

Comment: I have the answer for the other question you had if you would like to add it as a separate question

Comment: That would be great. I've asked it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325952/difference-between-internet-sharing-and-create-a-network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

You can share/extend a network from Wi-Fi to Wi=Fi as long as you have two network adapters. In fact I am doing it right now!

I suggest you share Wi-Fi **from the USB network adapter to the Internal Network Adapter**, and not the other way around as it might cause issues (see pictures).

I would also suggest [Panda Wireless PAU09 N600 Dual Band](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LY35HGO). I have used it with no problems. It works with Mac (Drivers needed), PC (Drivers needed), and Linux.  It's dual band, allowing you to connect to 5Ghz networks.  It support Monitor Mode, Packet Injection, and AP mode. The range is pretty good, would say about the same as the internal network adapter. It currently supports High Sierra and below. [Heres](http://www.pandawireless.com/Drivers%20%7C%20Panda%20Wireless.html) the drivers download page.

Additionally, you can look at [my answer over here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323912/263848) for how to use your Mac as a router and change lease time, DHCP settings, DNS settings, Port Forwarding, etc.

**Note:**  Parts of the solution provided there (^^) does not constantly work.

Some pictures:
[image]

---

**Note:**  I am in **no way affiliated with Panda Wireless**, or the product the I suggested. I do not gain from the purchase of the product. I am not promoting the product, just suggesting it as an adapter that I have found works.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have any recommended USB Wi-Fi adapters in a slightly cheaper range? I have seen plenty on amazon but am never certain about High Sierra compatibility.

Comment: @mahclark Not sure. But I heard the TP ones are pretty good. Just remember “you pay for what you get”, especially with technology