# Difference between Internet Sharing and 'Create a Network'

Tags: wifi, high-sierra

I have discovered two ways to share internet on my MacBook. Firstly, clicking on the Wi-Fi icon and selecting 'Create Network...'. Secondly, in System Preferences, Sharing > Internet Sharing and select 'To computers using: Wi-Fi'. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is simple:

- Ad-hoc (peer-to-peer) network
- Internet Sharing

When you click on *Create Network* from the WiFi icon in the top bar, you are creating an [ad-hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) network.  An ad-hoc network is just an *infrastructure-less* network that allows you to share resources to other *local* computers (i.e. file sharing).  There's typically no Internet access with this setup.  Typical use cases would be to share a file wirelessly, or to screen share (remote control) one machine with another for administration/maintenance.

*Internet Sharing*, when configured through System Preferences, turns your Mac into a router with with [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and firewall services.  A simple use case would be to allow *your* guests in hotel room to use the hotel internet through your login credentials.  This differs from an ad-hoc network inasmuch as you're *creating* the necessary infrastructure; the wireless access, the router, and the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that "create network" allows another wifi device to connect to your mac but not browse the internet through the mac's network connection.