# Map one IP to another

Tags: macos, network, pfctl

On Linux, I can use `iptables` to cause any incoming requests $FROM destined for some IP address to go to another $TO, regardless of whether $FROM and/or $TO where actually on the interface, or even registered on either of my address (for example, I can make any request for 2.2.2.2 to go to 8.8.8.8). Is it possible to do this on MacOS, either with `pfctl` or some other tool?

Here is my attempt:
`echo "rdr pass inet proto {tcp, udp} from any to 2.2.2.2 port 1:3000 -> 127.0.0.1" | sudo pfctl -ef -`

EDIT:
This works if $TO=127.0.0.1:

```
printf "rdr pass inet proto {tcp, udp} from any to 2.2.2.2 port 1:3000 -> 127.0.0.1\npass out route-to (lo0 127.0.0.1) from any to 2.2.2.2\n" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to extend it to any $TO

Comment: Something like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363099/how-to-forward-traffic-from-one-machine-to-another-with-pfctl?rq=1 ?

Comment: I have looked at it, but all of the machines was on the same LAN, and the top answer have `vlan0` specified. I want something that can work regardless of the what the IP address is.

Comment: Well, did you try to adapt it to your setup?

Comment: I did: here's what I tried --- `echo "rdr pass inet proto {tcp, udp} from any to 2.2.2.2 port 1:3000 -> 127.0.0.1" | sudo pfctl -ef -`. It didn't work.